How to upload jhipster frontend separately and run in Linux server
I want to know If I want to build the front end and the backend separately and upload it to a Linux server and run, what should be the correct way to do it. I believe just uploading the jar file and run won't suffice
I looked this up on all over the internet and docs. couldn't find an answer

Why do you want to do this? If it's so you can use a CDN, you can use CloudFront and pull all the frontend assets from the deployed JHipster app. If you want to separate them for another reason, you'll have to use JWT since all the other authentication methods use sessions.
